# Cambiar de posición los labels de una grafica en Ngx-Chart

Tags: css, html5, angular7

Estoy implementando Ngx-chart en un proyecto de angular version 7 y quería saber si es posible mover los labels que genera la grafica como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La grafica genera varios labels entre ellos: total y porcentajes intente modificarlos con CSS pero no aplica los estilos

```css
.advanced-pie-legend .total-value {
    font-size: 36px !important;
    position: left !important;
}

.advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items .legend-item .item-percent {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    position: rigth !important;
}
```

Este es el proyecto de angular que estoy utilizando

```html
<ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="single" [gradient]="gradient" (select)="onSelect($event)" (activate)="onActivate($event)" (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)">
</ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { single } from './data';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  single: any[];
  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  gradient: boolean = true;
  showLegend: boolean = true;
  showLabels: boolean = true;
  isDoughnut: boolean = false;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { single });
  }

  onSelect(data): void {
    console.log('Item clicked', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }

  onActivate(data): void {
    console.log('Activate', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }

  onDeactivate(data): void {
    console.log('Deactivate', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
}
```

No se si existirá alguna propiedad de la misma grafica para hacer eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que Angular acepte cambios en el css de algunas librerías como Angular material o el mismo ngx-charts, uno tiene que colocar `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` en el decorador del componente.

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

A mi me ha funcionando en muchos casos,
espero que te sirva.